# Impala: Show tables like query

Tags: hive, cloudera, hiveql, cloudera-cdh, impala

I am working with Impala and fetching the list of tables from the database with some pattern like below.

Assume i have a Database `bank`, and tables under this database are like below.

```
cust_profile
cust_quarter1_transaction
cust_quarter2_transaction
product_cust_xyz
....
....
etc
```

Now i am filtering like

```
show tables in bank like '*cust*'
```

It is returning the expected results like, which are the tables has a word `cust` in its name.

Now my requirement is **i want all the tables which will have `cust` in its name and table should not have `quarter2`**.

Can someone please help me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Execute from the shell and then filter**

```
impala-shell -q "show tables in bank like '*cust*'" | grep -v 'quarter2'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query the metastore**

```
 mysql -u root -p -e "select TBL_NAME from metastore.TBLS where TBL_NAME like '%cust%' and TBL_NAME not like '%quarter2%'";
```