# Hive Regex to select one or more occurrence of number

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have tables like

```
sales_import_1
sales_import_2
sales_import_export_1
```

I want to get  tables `sales_import_1` and `sales_import_2` as my query output.

I tried with query `show tables like 'sales_import_*'`.
 It will select all 3 tables .

How can I get only sales_import_1,sales_import_2?

Comment: can u explain a bit more what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You can have both with a non very elegant solution: `show tables like 'sales_import_1|sales_import_2';`

Comment: If you want to use regexp, you can execute query from shell (all tables) and filtering it by `grep`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42999498/impala-show-tables-like-query/43002994#43002994